# why not just 2 charts to make atlas for sphere?

Tags: differential-geometry, differential-topology

In http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Manifold_(mathematics)#Construction, it says that 6 charts can be used to make an atlas for a sphere. But the text shows that you have a chart for the northern hemisphere, and you can make a similar chart for the southern hemisphere. Hence, these two charts cover the entire sphere.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: charts should be open so the two hemispheres does not cover all sphere

Comment: Those two charts don't cover the great circle on the equator. So you need four more charts to fully cover that circle. You can cover the sphere with just two charts using [stereographic projection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stereographic_projection).

Answer (score 44, accepted):

The northern hemisphere and southern hemisphere **don't** cover the entire sphere. The sphere is 
$$\mathbb{S}^2=\{(x,y,z)\in\mathbb{R}^3\mid x^2+y^2+z^2=1\}.$$

The northern and southern hemispheres are, respectively,
$$\mathbb{S}_N^2=\{(x,y,z)\in\mathbb{S}^2\mid z>0\},\qquad\mathbb{S}_S^2=\{(x,y,z)\in\mathbb{S}^2\mid z<0\}.$$
These miss the equator $\{(x,y,z)\in\mathbb{S}^2\mid z=0\}$. Adding "east" and "west" hemispheres 
$$\mathbb{S}_W^2=\{(x,y,z)\in\mathbb{S}^2\mid x>0\},\qquad\mathbb{S}_E^2=\{(x,y,z)\in\mathbb{S}^2\mid x<0\}$$
*still* doesn't get everything: we are missing the points on the equator $(0,1,0)$ and $(0,-1,0)$. Finally, adding the last two hemispheres (east and west, only rotated 90 degrees) covers the entire sphere.

---

This raises the question, why are we defining our hemispheres with $>$ and $<$? Perhaps we could instead use $\leq $ and $\geq$, and this would let us cover the sphere with two hemispheres?

The answer is that [a chart of a manifold needs to be a homeomorphism between an **open** subset of the manifold with an **open** subset of $\mathbb{R}^n$](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/CoordinateChart.html). The sets
$$\{(x,y,z)\in\mathbb{S}^2\mid z\geq 0\},\qquad\{(x,y,z)\in\mathbb{S}^2\mid z\leq 0\}$$
are not open in the topology of $\mathbb{S}^2$ (which is the [subspace topology](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subspace_topology) inherited from $\mathbb{R}^3$). So we can't use them as coordinate neighborhoods in the manifold structure of $\mathbb{S}^2$.

---

It does warrant mentioning, however, that we *can* cover the sphere using only two charts, via [stereographic projection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stereographic_projection#Definition). The two open subsets of $\mathbb{S}^2$ acting as our coordinate domains are 
$$\mathbb{S}^2-\{(0,0,1)\},\qquad\mathbb{S}^2-\{(0,0,-1)\}$$
and for each, we project a line from the removed point to the plane, which one can check gives a continuous map. It is a tedious (but important) exercise to demonstrate that the smooth structure determined by stereographic projection is the same as that of the hemispheres (i.e., they are [compatible atlases](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Differential_manifold#Compatible_atlases)).

Comment: I have reluctantly downvoted this answer.  Although everything stated is correct, I feel that in context, it is extremely important to mention the fact that the sphere can, in fact, be covered by two charts (e.g., using stereographic projection). Without this remark, the answer strikes me as incomplete, in a serious way.

Comment: @Charles: You have a valid point - my phrasing was not ideal. Jacob's comment above, though, does mention that the stereographic projection lets us cover the sphere with two charts. I will put this information in my answer.

Comment: Why can't we just have the hemispheres plus an extra epsilon (still open) to cover the equator? Or is it just that the stereographic projection is nicer?

Comment: @Harry: Dear Harry, You can certainly do what you suggest (have the hemispheres plus epsilon).  Perhaps  stereographic projection is just more traditional?  (Personally I prefer your suggestion, as being more intuitive.)  Regards,

Comment: While it is true that you can cover ${\mathbb S}^2$ with two charts I feel more at ease if individual charts as well as intersections of  charts are homeomorphic to disks. For this you need 4 charts.

Comment: @Matt oh, okay. Thank you!

Comment: Downvote removed.

Comment: @Harry: When I think about the sphere for qualitative arguments, I tend to imagine the sort of charts you suggest. But if you ever actually want to do computations, stereographic projection is almost certainly easier to deal with than "hemispheres enlarged by $\epsilon$." Also (and this is the real reason I used it in my comment), when you want to give someone an example of a covering of the sphere by two charts, "stereographic projection" is faster to say and less likely to be disputed than "hemispheres enlarged by $\epsilon$."

Comment: @Charles That makes sense as well.

Comment: @MattE But if you add that extra epsilon you will cover the equator, where you may find that your parametrization is not invertible... This is what happens when using spherical coordinates to define your charts, which leads you to define six different ones for the reasons given in this answer. Is this not an issue here?